# Fitting PCA using the model.matrix function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pca

So I am working with a data-set involving data regarding the passengers on the Titanic which you may find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/titanic/index.html).

So here I am using the train data provided. I would like to create a model matrix of the dataset that only contains numbers (no factors!) by using the
model.matrix function.

After which, remove the Survived variable from this dataset.

From this matrix, I would like to fit a PCA to the matrix from the previous step and plot the scores of the observations (using only the first 2 dimensions) and color them according to the Survived variable.

I have tried a few ways of doing this but it does not seem accurate nor does it color.

```
 library(readr)
 library(dplyr)
 titanic_train <- read_csv("C:/Users/johnt/Desktop/Statistical Data Mining/HW 1/train.csv")

 titanic_train <- titanic_train %>% 
   select(Survived, Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare, Embarked) %>% 
   mutate(Fare = log(Fare))


 ###### Model Matrix

 mm <- titanic_train %>% 
   select(Pclass, Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare, Survived) 

 titan <- model.matrix(-Survived ~., mm)

 #Clean it up
 titan <- titan[,-1] #remove intercept column
 titan <- scale(titan)
 titan[is.na(titan)] <- 0

 #PCA
 titan2 <-prcomp(titan[,-5], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
 titan2


 plot(titan2$x[,1:2],col=mm$Survived)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `ggbiplot(titan2)` ?

Of course if you do you will have to filter for use of only the first two columns before running it on `prcomp`

And could you give an example of how you'd like the PCA to look ?

Comment: ggbiplot is unavailable for R version 3.5.2 :/ and I am actually unsure how this is supposed to look (grad student here trying to figure out what PCA is)

Comment: run the following and try installing again: `source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")`
`biocLite("ggbiplot")`

Comment: still can't find it even when I call library(ggbiplot)

Comment: Ok then try downloading a package called factoextra, it does the same thing. I actually prefer it to ggbiplot. Let me know if it works for you